# How to Add a Column

Tags: python, sql, indexing

I'm looking for a sql or python solution to add am index to my table:

Lets say I have:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| City  | State |  ZIP  |
+-------+-------+-------+
| MIAMI | FL    | 33157 |
| MIAMI | FL    | 33158 |
| MIAMI | FL    | 33159 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want the table to add an index that is unique by city and state irregardless of zipcode to look like:

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| City  | State |  ZIP  | Index |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| MIAMI | FL    | 33157 |     1 |
| MIAMI | FL    | 33158 |     2 |
| MIAMI | FL    | 33159 |     3 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use this SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

The added 'id' column will be unique for each record. And will be auto incremented by one in each record automatically.
I think it is possible in other SQL database engines, too.

Comment: I've tried ALTER TABLE 'cities' ADD INDEX 'id' ('city','state'); but I don't see an id column added any ideas?

Comment: Because you're just making ('city', 'state') columns be an index for you, not creating new column

Comment: how do i crete a new column?

Comment: I've written the SQL command to add a new column. ```ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;```